# How to align six imagebuttons in 2 columns with 3 rows in android studio?

Tags: android, layout

I'm an android noob and I'm trying to figure out how the layouts work. Can't quite figure it out just yet though. I've got an activity in android studio where i want to display six imagebuttons aligned over 2 colums over 3 rows. Like this:

```
 ___________________
|                   |
| button 1 button 2 |
|                   |
| button 3 button 4 |
|                   |
| button 5 button 6 |
|___________________|
```

I would like the space between the buttons and the edge of the frame to be the same so that the buttons are equally displayed over the entire screen. I've tried working with a grid layout but the buttons either stick to the side of the screen or stay next to each other. What is the best way to get this done?

my xml so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="6">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:background="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@drawable/image2"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:background="@drawable/image3"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:background="@drawable/image4"/>

     <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:background="@drawable/image5"/>

     <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:background="@drawable/image6"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Question 2:

I've given the images 150dp width and height so that the dimension of the images doesn't change. If i set it to something like match_parent the image distorts into an unequal width and height. Is there anyway to make it so that the image scales correctly without a set height and width?

Comment: set cloumwidth property of gridLayout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the weight :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

With the weight the button take place equally in your view, if you want to add some space between button you just have to add the element space and assign it a weight. Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

- `android:layout_gravity` sets the gravity of the `View` or `Layout`
  in its parent.

You can add `android:layout_gravity = center` to the `GridLayout` and it will center the grid.

- `android:gravity` sets the gravity of the content of the `View` its
  used on.

so you can add something like `android:gravity = center` to the `GridLayout` and that will center its elements.

and for the buttons not to stick you can add padding to each `ImageButton` f.e.

`android:paddingBottom="6dp"
android:paddingLeft="6dp"
android:paddingRight="6dp"
android:paddingTop="6dp"`

Answer (score 1):

Set the **android:layout_gravity=right** in **ImageButton** layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:columnCount="2"
 android:rowCount="6">



<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/date"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@drawable/date"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:background="@drawable/date"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:background="@drawable/date"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:background="@drawable/date"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:background="@drawable/date"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>
```